# PyCharm 2018.1.4 not seeing classes?

Tags: python, pycharm

Using Python 3.5.2 and PyQt5 I am attempting to build an application using PyCharm 2018.1.4.  When I enter the code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
```

PyCharm complains that the module could not be found.  Attempting to run the script I get the following error:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.10' not found (required by /mnt/DevServer/Python/CliReports/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so)
```

Running python from the command prompt and using the same import above works fine.  Am I missing a configuration in PyCharm?

Comment: Type `which python` in your terminal (or `where python` in windows). Then check if PyCharm uses that same interpreter in the settings. Not sure if that is the issue, but worth checking

Comment: Python is using /usr/bin/python; however pycharm has created a virtual enviroment and is using a venv/bin/python folder under my project folder

Comment: That means you have to install pyqt5 in that virtualenv, or change the interpreter

Comment: Under the project interpreter, the package PyQt5 is installed.

Comment: Try googling for `qt virtualenv`. There are some tutorials available on what to take care of if you want to use it inside a virtualenv